# How to make sidebar height equal to window's height?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress Twenty Fifteen child theme to move its left sidebar to right side.

[My child theme](http://www.twentyfifteenrightsidebar.com/) sidebar's height is not equal to window's height like the [original theme](http://twentyfifteendemo.wordpress.com/).

This is my `sidebar` CSS:

```
.sidebar {
float: right;
margin-right: 0px;
max-width: 413px;
position: relative !important;
width: 29.4118%;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

I have tried `height:100%;` and `height:auto;` but it still not working.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you want the Sidebar to scroll or be fixed

Comment: Your height is not working probably because the container doesn't have a set height either.

Comment: When user scroll, I want the sidebar scrollable with full height white background. @j_s_stack

Comment: @slime any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You need to post more code. We need to see the HTML structure and relevant CSS. In the meantime, try: `height:100vh`

Answer (score 1):

You can use css3 viewport-percentages.

For example,  setting height equal to:  height:100vh;,  will make your div equal to 100% of the height of the view port.

You can read more about it here:

[Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

or have a look at this fiddle I put together here. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Note that CSS3 vh is not supported by older browsers,  so you may be better off accomplishing this with jQuery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery would be your best bet.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $(".sidebar").css("height", windowHeight);
});
```

The scroll function will resize the sidebar if the browser size changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be fixed (always there, like in the original theme) then you can set it to `position: fixed` with a `top: 0`, `bottom: 0` and a proper left/right settings (or width).

If you want it to stay at the top and not stick to the viewport, then you could place it in `position: absolute` with a `top: 0`, `bottom: 0` and proper left/right, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution I used, after looking at the styles used on http://materializecss.com/collections.html - the side navigation is similar to what I am attempting to make - I found that this worked for me:

```
height: calc(100% + 2em);
```

Well.. more precisely, THIS worked for me:

```
height: ~"calc(100% + 2em)";
```

^ I'm using LESS, and if it's not escaped, I'd end up with a height of 102%.